# Rutherford scattering experiment, part 2

Tags: scattering, atoms, metals

This question is a continuation of my previous question [Rutherford scattering experiment, part 1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/576896/rutherford-scattering-experiment-part-1) , but can be considered independently.

Around 1906-1914 several classical experiments on scattering of $\alpha$-particles on gold and platinum foils have been performed by Rutherford, Geiger, and Marsden.

> In standard textbooks I looked at, the interaction of $\alpha$-particles with electrons in the foils is neglected without a satisfactory explanation. What is the quantitative reason for that, preferably the one known to the group of Rutherford at the time?

**Remark.** According to my understanding one should be able to compare the speed of $\alpha$-particles to the speed of electrons (both bound and free ones) and to show that the latter is not much higher than the former.

Comment: An electron has ~1/8000 the mass of an $\alpha$ particle. Again, you can't backscatter an $\alpha$ off an electron.

Comment: @JonCuster: Correct, but if the electron moves really fast, the $\alpha$-particle still may backscatter. Rutherford and others should have been able to estimate the speed of electrons.

Comment: You should calculate how fast the electron must go to backscatter a multi-MeV alpha particle.

Comment: @JonCuster: Calculate based on what data? In the literature I know electrons are systematically ignored in this topic. Just knowledge of electron mass and charge is not sufficient for this problem. Some extra data should be known in order to conclude that the speed of electron is not much higher than the speed of $\alpha$-particle.

Comment: Do the kinematics of the collision, that is all. The factor of 8000 in mass is hard to overcome for a multi-MeV alpha.